# Clojure: Merge 2 vectors of maps

Tags: clojure

I have 2 vectors of maps: employ-base and employ1. I want to merge the 2 vectors where employ1 has higher priority than employ-base. So if employ1 has the records use them, else use the record from employ-base. What is the best way to do it in clojure?

from:

```
(def employ-base
  [{:id 1 :name "Aaron" :income 0}
   {:id 2 :name "Ben" :income 0}
   {:id 3 :name "Carry" :income 0}])

(def employ1
  [{:id 1 :name "Aaron" :income 1000}   
   {:id 3 :name "Carry" :income 2000}])
```

to:

```
(def employ1
  [{:id 1 :name "Aaron" :income 1000}
   {:id 2 :name "Ben" :income 0}
   {:id 3 :name "Carry" :income 2000}])
```

Comment: Both of your recent questions (and, actually, now that I look, two other recent questions by you) follow the same theme: things are hard because you're using the wrong data structure. You can tell, because the answers you've received to your questions involve immediately putting the data into a map, keyed by id, a much more convenient format. If you do that up front, all sorts of transformations will become much easier.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the problem, the really map doesn't have ids. there is not unique keys in the map. it's something like: (def employ1
  [{:fname "Aaron" :lname "Smith" :income 1000}   
   {:fname "Carry" :lname "Smith" :income 2000}])

Comment: In your question, the phrase "if employ1 has records" is unclear. What does "has" mean? Are they equal? Is only the `:id` equal? Is the combination of `:id` and `:name` equal? Or in from your comment, is it the combination of `:fname` and `lname`, or just one of them? Depending on what you want, the solution will look differently.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `:id` is unique per employee, you could group the maps by `:id` then merge each grouping of maps per `:id`:

```
(map
 #(apply merge (val %))
 (merge-with concat
             (group-by :id employ-base)
             (group-by :id employ1)))
=> ({:id 1, :name "Aaron", :income 1000}
    {:id 2, :name "Ben", :income 0}
    {:id 3, :name "Carry", :income 2000})
```

The precedence of merging is maintained by merging `employ1` *after* `employe-base`, since `merge` and `merge-with` prefer the rightmost values.